# Forzar cambio de placeholder en input

Tags: javascript

Tengo un código en HTML el cual intento acceder con javascript al valor placeholder para cambiar su string, pero al realizar la siguiente función no efectúa el cambio.

```
<input 
   type="search" value="" name="s" id="yith-s" 
   class="yith-s" placeholder="Buscar productos" 
   data-append-to=".search-navigation" 
   data-loader-icon="http://www.urkam.cl/wp-content/plugins/yith-woocommerce-ajax-search-premium/assets/images/preloader.gif" 
   data-min-chars="3" style="padding: 8px;" autocomplete="off">
```

---

```
[
        function ModifyPlaceHolder () {
        let input = document.getElementById("yith-s");
        input.placeholder = "No need to fill this field";
  };

]
```

Comment: para tener en cuenta: IE < 10 fallaría

Answer (score 1):

He copiado el código y le he agregado un `addEventListener`, ya que no se podia iniciar la funcion sin el. Prueba como te digo, a mi me funciona.

Ya que supongo por lo que has puesto que o se te ha olvidado el listener, o no sabias que hace. Si es lo último agrego una pequeña explicación

`document` es cualquier elemento presente en un documento (como ves, el propio documento en este caso, se puede sustituir por variables o lo que quieras), al que accedemos por el medio que elijamos, bien por su id, por su etiqueta o las propiedades de otro nodo.

`DOMContentLoaded` es la acción o suceso por el cual el Listener, ejecuta la función. (En este caso DOMContenLoaded, es en cuanto cargue la web)[Lista de eventos en web](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events)

Arriba agrego una lista de eventos, por si el que yo he agregado en el ejemplo no te sirve.

Este es tu código editado, como explico arriba y funciona.

```js
function ModifyPlaceHolder () 
{
let input = document.getElementById("yith-s");
input.placeholder = "No need to fill this field";
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ModifyPlaceHolder)
```

Y el html lo he dejado como el que tu tienes.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>asda</title>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="search" value="" name="s" id="yith-s" class="yith-s" placeholder="Buscar productos" data-append-to=".search-navigation" data-loader-icon="http://www.urkam.cl/wp-content/plugins/yith-woocommerce-ajax-search-premium/assets/images/preloader.gif" data-min-chars="3" style="padding: 8px;" autocomplete="off">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Y lo dicho, tu función esta bien pero por lo que veo le falta un listener que inicie la función, como no se en que situación lo quieres cambiar, tendrás que buscar en la pagina que te he adjuntado.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se accesasa los elementos del DOM por medio de javascript nativo con el método `getElementById`, este devuelve un array [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/NodeList) con el o los elementos. Para poder cambiar el placeholder con una función podría ser de la siguiente manera:

```
function ModifyPlaceHolder (idElement) {
    let input = document.getElementById(idElement)[0];
    input.placeholder = "No need to fill this field";   
}
```

Para llamar a la función se podría hacer de dos formar, identificarlo con el id o con su clase, para llamarlo con el id lo puede hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
ModifyPlaceHolder('input#id_del_input')
```

Para llamarlo tomando la clase como rederencia sería de esta forma:

```
ModifyPlaceHolder('input.id_del_input')
```

Al devolver solo un elemento la posición del elemento en el `NodeList` será `0`, la función se podría extender y validar en si el lenght de input es > 1 pasear y cambiar el placeholder a varios inputs